# Add a reminder for same review item on multiple queues

Tags: feature-request, review

Many times when browsing the review queues on SharePoint exchange I see the same item on multiple review tabs. For example is pretty common that a new user (-> first answer tab) will post an answer on an old post (->late answer tab).

I know that this is just normal. I also know that in that case I can just select the "I am done button" and move forward, since I have already processed the item. What I am asking is to make the "You have already done this" more evident. Can some sort of pop up be added somewhere that remember me what I have chosen in the past?

My request is based on two "issues":

- first, I don't know if the system would allow me to add a second flag- for example a "not an answer one". If i can do this, I will only add noise if I do not notice that I have processed the same answer before and select the same item again.
- second, if I miss-click I can at last notice the second time if I have done an error and try to correct it (suppose I have clicked the wrong flag category, I can somehow alert a mod that I have made a mistake and maybe avoid some lost time).

I know that this may seem a small thing, but I believe it could help. Fell free to disregard this suggestion if the current system will block a second review anyway.

PS: little related - why some review categories offer some command that others don't? Specifically, why the autocomment "this is not an answer/ this is a comment/etc" seems to be limited to low quality reviews? Shouldn't the "this is not an answer" auto comment option be useful on other tabs also?

Comment: @casperOne Thanks for the tag fix - I was going to post this as a discussion, then switched to request and forgot to remove the old tag.

Comment: Similar post on physics.se: [Why do some posts show up in more than one review queue? Could we stop it?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4065)

Comment: @episanty Good to know. As you pointed out, this issue has already been answered in the past: having the same item in multiple quee is considered by design. That's why I am asking something different - leave the item but point out what you have done before. The system already has that info, it must have it because the "I'm done" button is active by default if you have processed the same question in the past.